# combine a uint array with a string array

Tags: c#

I have these 2 fairly large arrays, one with pointers and one with strings to id them so I can access them with int z being their index. I occasionally come back to them to do stuff with it.

```
        //LUTs(names start, names end, descriptions strart, descriptions end)
UInt32[,] multiPointer = {{0x81656650, 0x816571F8, 0x816571FC, 0x81657DA4},//item
                          {0x81671DE0, 0x81671FE8, 0x81672820, 0x81672A28},//chest
                          {0x81671FEC, 0x816721DC, 0x81672A2C, 0x81672C1C},//arm
                          {0x816721E0, 0x816723D4, 0x81672C20, 0x81672E14},//waist
                          {0x816723D8, 0x816725C8, 0x81672E18, 0x81673008},//legging
                          {0x816725CC, 0x816727FC, 0x8167300C, 0x8167323C},//headgear
                          {0x81672800, 0x8167281C, 0x81673240, 0x8167325C},//talisman
                          {0x81666B20, 0x81666C94, 0x81667290, 0x81667404},//GS
                          {0x81666C98, 0x81666E04, 0x81667408, 0x81667574},//SnS
                          {0x81666E08, 0x81666F5C, 0x81667578, 0x816676CC},//hammer
                          {0x81667108, 0x8166728C, 0x81667878, 0x816679FC},//lance
                          {0x81670600, 0x8167064C, 0x816706F4, 0x81670740},//bg frame
                          {0x816705B0, 0x816705FC, 0x816706A4, 0x816706F0},//bg barrel
                          {0x81670650, 0x816706A0, 0x81670744, 0x81670794},//bg stock
                          {0x81666F60, 0x8166700C, 0x816676D0, 0x8166777C},//LS
                          {0x81667010, 0x81667104, 0x81667780, 0x81667874},//SwA
                          {0x8168423C, 0x816842DC, 0x0,0x0},//monster
                          {0x816856F8, 0x816858CC, 0x816858D0, 0x81685AA4},//title
                          {0x81656FEC, 0x816571F8, 0x0, 0x0}//decorations
                         };
string[] stuff = { "Item", 
                   "Chest", 
                   "Arm", 
                   "Waist", 
                   "Legging", 
                   "Headgear", 
                   "Talisman", 
                   "Great Sword", 
                   "Sword and Shield",
                   "Hammer", "Lance", 
                   "Bowgun Frame", 
                   "Bowgun Barrel", 
                   "Bowgun Stock", 
                   "Longsword", 
                   "Switch Axe", 
                   "Monster", 
                   "Title",
                   "Decorations"
                 };
```

Sorry about the terrible names. Before they were 5 different arrays until I learned about multidimensional arrays. But then I can't combine the strings with the hex. Is there a way to combine these 2 arrays so that it looks neater?

Comment: I don't get it... What you need in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class that contains a `string` and 4 `UInt32`

```
public class Item {
    public UInt32 Value1 { get; private set; }
    public UInt32 Value2 { get; private set; }
    public UInt32 Value3 { get; private set; }
    public UInt32 Value4 { get; private set; }
    public string Stuff { get; private set; }
}
```

Now you can create an array of `Item`:

```
public Item[] items = {
    { 0x81656650, 0x816571F8, 0x816571FC, 0x81657DA4, "Item" },
}
```

And so on...

Comment: hmm. That works. Thanks guys. It looks way better now. I can even add functions to it.I wish I asked earlier. Now I have to redo some code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a class to hold the information? It will have a lot more meaning than a couple of arrays:

```
class Thing 
{
  public string ThingType { get;set; }

  public UInt32 NameStart { get; set; }

  public UInt32 NameEnd { get; set; }

  public UInt32 DescriptionStart { get; set; }

  public UInt32 DescriptionEnd { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can keep a list of `Things`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also use the linq query as yours structure

```
var r1 = Enumerable.Range(0, multiPointer.GetLength(0))
                    .Select(i => new
                        {
                            Index = i,
                            Col1 = multiPointer[i, 0],
                            Col2 = multiPointer[i, 1],
                            Col3 = multiPointer[i, 2],
                            Col4 = multiPointer[i, 3]
                        });

        var r2 = stuff.Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v });


        var result = from p in r1
                     from q in r2
                     where p.Index == q.Index
                     select new
                     {
                         Stuff = q.Value,
                         Col1 = p.Col1,
                         Col2 = p.Col2,
                         Col3 = p.Col3,
                         Col4 = p.Col4,
                     };

        foreach (var r in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1} , {2} , {3} , {4}", r.Stuff, r.Col1, r.Col2, r.Col3, r.Col4));
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I've never used linq query before so I'll have to do some research before I can say this is better. Thanks for the idea.